# MVVM Xamarin open new window from ViewModel - How to eliminate reference to the view

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I want to open a new modal window using the MVVM pattern in a Xamarin Forms app. I have researched opening a new window with the MVVM pattern, which has got me this far, but the thing about windows in Xamarin forms, is they need a reference to the current page (view) to open a new window (new view) from. This forces me to pass a reference to the current page (view) from my viewModel, to my window factory, to launch the new window from. This is a violation of MVVM. My goal is to get rid of any references to views from within my viewModel. That is my question, how do  I do that? My code here happens to be a modal window, but normal windows also need a reference to the page it is launching from. Here is my code and you will see what I mean:

Window Factory (look at the CreateNewWindow method):

```
public interface IWindowFactory
    {
        void CreateNewWindow();
    }

    public class ProductionWindowFactory: IWindowFactory
    {
        Page launchFromPage;
        BackLogViewModel viewModel;

        public ProductionWindowFactory(BackLogViewModel ViewModel, Page page)
        {
            viewModel = ViewModel;
            launchFromPage = page;
        }

        public void CreateNewWindow()
        {
            AddStoryPage window = new AddStoryPage (new AddStoryViewModel (viewModel));
            launchFromPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync (window);
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel that opens a new modal window (look particularly at the AddTask Command):

```
public class BackLogViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private IWindowFactory m_windowFactory;

        public void DoOpenNewWindow()
        {
            m_windowFactory.CreateNewWindow();
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Story> AllMyStories { get; set; }
        private string _updated;
        public string Updated
        {
            get 
            {
                return _updated;
            }
            set 
            {
                _updated = value;
                OnPropertyChanged ();
            }
        }

        public Page mypage;
        public BackLogViewModel (Page page)
        {
            Updated = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            mypage = page;
            AllMyStories = new ObservableCollection<Story> ();

        }

        public ICommand Save
        {
            get {
                return new Command (() => {
                    Updated = DateTime.Now.ToString();
                });
            }
        }

        public ICommand AddTask
        {
            get {
                return new Command ( () => {
                    m_windowFactory = new ProductionWindowFactory(this, mypage);
                    DoOpenNewWindow();
                });
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) 
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs (propertyName));
            }
        }

        private Command selectCmd;
        public Command Select {
            get {
                this.selectCmd = this.selectCmd ?? new Command<Story>(p => 
                    {
                        var monkey = p as Story;
                        if (monkey == null) return;
                        Page z = new Views.StoryPage(p);
                        mypage.Navigation.PushAsync(z);
                    }
                );
                return this.selectCmd;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How do I get rid of the reference to the current page (view) within my viewModel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have since found [This tutorial on navigating views from the ViewModel in Xamarin](http://www.johankarlsson.net/2014/09/navigation-from-viewmodel-using.html)

It basically does what I was already doing but instead of passing the full view to the ViewModel, it passes only the INavigation interface of the view, and uses that to navigate from. It states that it can be argued that it is violating MVVM, but has the attitude of "so be it", I suspect because no obvious and easy alternatives exist. There may be alternatives that do not reference any part of the view from the ViewModel, but in order to keep moving forward I have opted for this easy solution. I have kept my window factory in order to not specify a concrete window to build in my ViewModel.